# Bring a certain activity to front

Tags: android, android-activity

Let's say: I have 2 classes MainActivity and SecondActivity

At first, my app starts with an instance of MainActivity. In MainActivity, there're several buttons which will start a SecondActivity if they're clicked. And everytime start a SecondActivty, I put a diffirent parameter by putExtra function to that SecondActivity, so every SecondActivity will display every different content.

And I used this code in SecondActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

So everytime back button is pressed in a SecondActivity, it won't be destroyed.

Now, for example, I have this scenario:

> MainActivity **==click_a_button==>** SencondActivity(instance1)
>   **==press_back_button==>** MainActivity **==click_another_button==>** SecondActivity(instance2) **==press_back_button==>** MainActivity
>   **(*)**

Stop at step **(*)**: from here (in MainActivity), user presses the button which started **instance1**, my question is how to bring exactly that SecondActivity(instance1) to front?

P/S: I read about `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but don't know how to use it in my case.

Comment: I think if you press back button on an Activity instance, it'll be destroyed by the SO and you will not be able to bring to front the instance1

Comment: I have that line `moveTaskToBack(true);` in my SecondActivity, so it won't be destroyed

Comment: I think you are confused. `moveTaskToBack()` does NOT change the order of the activities within the task. It seems like you are going through a lot of trouble to get around the standard behaviour. Why can't you just let SecondActivity finish (and get destroyed) when the user uses the "back" button to return to the MainActivity, and let a new instance of SecondActivity get created when the user chooses the next thing. What is the reasoning behind your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Set the lanchMode of Your SecondActivity to SingleTop.

```
     <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: can you explain more about your idea with sample code? Thanks

Comment: sorry, i meant the Java code, which can help to bring exactly an instance of SecondActivity to font.